Does a locally free resolution of a sheaf induces an exact sequnce in cohomology?
Asumme we have a locally free resolution of a sheaf $\mathscr{E}$ on a projective variety
$ 0 \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}_0 \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}_1 \cdots \longrightarrow \mathscr{E} \longrightarrow 0$
Does this resolution induces an exact sequence in cohomology?
I am intereseted in cases where $\mathscr{E}$ is reflexive and in particular where $\mathscr{E}$ is locally free

Do you mean "locally free"?

yes, thanks! I corrected the title

What do you mean by “exact sequence induced by a resolution”?

You should also correct the first sentence. Anyway, the answer is no, what you have instead of an exact sequence is a spectral sequence.

Thanks, @Sasha - could you please give me some references regarding this?

This is a general fact of homological algebra, so you can use any textbook discussing this.

@FShrike: In this particular case the hypercohomology spectral sequence works. But it is a special case of the spectral sequence obtained when you apply, say, the derived functor of a left exact functor to an exact sequence, and this can be found in textbooks.

@Sasha Thanks for confirming. I meant Cartan-Eilenberg resolution.. and I take back my claim, this is in Weibel's textbook e.g. it's just not presented quite in this way - I was unsure. So I think there is a spectral sequence $E_1^{p,q}=\mathcal{H}^q(\mathscr{F}_p)\implies0$ convergent to zero; the first horizontal differentials arise from the sheaf morphisms $\mathscr{F}p\to\mathscr{F}{p+1}$. Is this what you mean?

I'm not sure how much information can be extracted from this however. One thing I can see, since all sheaves are quasi-coherent here, is if the variety embeds into projective space of dimension $n$ then we should be able to infer $\mathcal{H}^n(\mathscr{F}_k)\to\mathcal{H}^n(\mathscr{E})$ is surjective.

@FShrike: It is not a good idea to write $\mathcal{H}$ for the global cohomology of a sheaf, it is better to write $H(X,\mathcal{F})$ where $X$ is the underlying variety.
